# want to use my own language babel but clashing with document class

Tags: babel, document-classes, package-options, option-clash, documentclass

I want to use mongolian babel with the other document class but it crashes everytime.

```
\documentclass[colophon, english]{phduio}

\usepackage{phdstyle}   % Custom style
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % Dummy text
\usepackage[mongolian]{babel}
```

and it says

! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package babel.
The package babel has already been loaded with options:
[]
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
[mongolian]
Adding the global options:
,mongolian
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.

and as it says document class declaration may fix this. Does it mean that i can't use this documentclass when i use other language babel ?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the code of `phduio.cls` (and possibly `phdstyle.sty`): If you are lucky, `\documentclass[colophon, mongolian]{phduio}` helps, but if `phduio.cls` (or `phdstyle.sty`) hard-codes `english` you are out of luck.

Comment: There are many issues that will arise using this class/package combination with `mongolian`. The `phdstyle` package loads all sorts of things that are incompatible. The `phduio` class uses `english` as a class option to define an internal command `\phduio@thesis` but the option also gets passed to `babel`. You can remove the `english` option, and use `\makeatletter \def \phduio@thesis{Thesis}\makeatother` but then a whole host of other problems arise. Looks like a lot of work, and not work for a single question here.

Comment: Does `\PassOptionsToPackage{mongolian}{babel}` work for you? See p6 of the `babel` manual.

Comment: nope it doesn't work but thanks

Comment: As this solution should work, I've downloaded the style files to see what's happening, and I've discovered a problem: both `mongolian` and `phdstyle.sty` are defining a macro with the same name (`\C`). Since both redefinitions are inside `phdstyle.sty`, the issue cannot be easily fixed without patching it.